# Portal Fantasy Book?

Tags: story-identification, dragons

Okay, I'm looking for this book that I've read a long time ago.  It's mostly about this girl and her friends who get transported into a magical land. Where she becomes queen of the entire land and has domain over magical creatures. One of her friends become her king (by mistake) and turns into a dragon and another one (not really her friend, just a bully) becomes her maid. There's even this funny scene where the furniture starts attacking her, when she tried using it. And her best friend who becomes a druid? They have to fight this wizard (I think) in order to get home. It's definitely a series. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: When did you read this? High school? Middle school? Early adulthood? If you can give us a date range, it may help.

Comment: Could be the Landover books by Terry Brooks, which started with "Magic Kingdom For Sale: Sold!"?

Comment: Sounds like you could be merging multiple books in your memory. Half of it sounds like Voyage of the Dawn Treader

Comment: I know exactly what I read, I'm not mixing up books. I've never even read the Narnia series. I checked it up, it's not "Magic Kingdom For Sale: Sold!" And I read it in high school.

Comment: Possibly the Achives of Anthropos: http://childrensbooks.wikia.com/wiki/The_Archives_of_Anthropos